# Twitter plugins arent working with hebrew

Tags: jquery

im trying to use plugins such as 'tweetquote' , im changing lang:en to lang:he
but it isnt working..

any suggestions?

Comment: the 'lang' suppose to filter tweets only for this langauge, 
so lang: en will show only english, when i change to lang: he, it doesnt show anything (when there are hebrew tweets)